# Unable to edit file through sudo permission

Tags: linux, sudo

I am trying to setup sudo permission for an account to have full access to  all files under certain directory.

I have made the following entry in sudoers file

```
itg ALL= NOPASSWD: /apps/pgm/admin/
```

The file which I trying to modify and execute under /apps/pgm/admin/ path has the following permssion.

> `-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 6034 Oct  2 02:00 ptTomcat.ksh`

Though I am able to execute the above script through sudo, when I try to edit this file through sudo I am getting the following error

Sorry, user itg is not allowed to execute '/bin/vi /apps/pgm/admin/ptTomcat.ksh' as root
I am running Linux

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user cannot execute '/bin/vi' as root as you haven't added that command to /etc/sudoers for that particular user.

Try something similar to:

```
itg ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/vi /apps/pgm/admin
```